# java - KeyListener fails to detect collision (platformer game)

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I am making a Java game, completely free of any external libraries or engines. Everything is doing fine, but I encountered a problem with the KeyListener. I do not understand why this is happening.

Whenever I animate the `Character`, which is extending `Object` (another custom class I coded) with `velX`, and with custom collision detection it works fine, and the `Character` stops moving whenever the `Character` `Object` collides with the `Block` `Object`; i.e.

ObjectController

```
Character c = new Character();
```

Character (`extends Object`)

```
public void checkCollision(LinkedList<Object> objects){
    for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
        if(this.bounds.getRCol().intersects(objects.get(i).bounds.getLCol())){
            setVelX(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Object

```
public void tick(LinkedList<Object> objects){
    x += velX;
    y += velY;
    checkCollision(objects)
}
```

KeyListener (working version, but I want the animation to stop after key is released)

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    c.setVelX(1);
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
    // nothing 
}
```

KeyListener (this version works, the animation starts when key pressed, stops when key is released, but the collision detection doesn't work)

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    c.setVelX(1);
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
    c.setVelX(0);
}
```

I have programmed every class correctly, or at least I feel so. The right and left collision rectangles are correctly placed on all of the `Object`s.

So why isn't this working? Am I doing it wrong? Or is it Swing's KeyListener's fault?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you need more information, please comment below and I would love to put more information!

Thanks, ProgrammersDude.

**EDIT - Update 1**

There is a class called `Panel.class`, based on `JPanel` It is the main container of all panels.

Then there is a `Subpanel.class`, which extends `JPanel`, too. It is an abstract class and inside of that class the `tick()` is called.

```
package com.platformer.main;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public abstract class Subpanel extends JPanel implements Runnable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public boolean loaded = false;
    public Thread loop = null;

    public Subpanel(){
        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.requestFocusInWindow();

        init();

        loop = new Thread(this);
        loop.start();
    }

    public void init(){
        load();
        loaded = true;
    }

    public abstract void load();

    public void run(){
        while(loaded){
            tick();
            repaint();
            try{
                Thread.sleep(17);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){

            }
        }
    }

    public abstract void tick();

    BufferedImage buffer;
    Graphics bg;

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        buffer = (BufferedImage) this.createImage(Start.WIDTH,    Start.HEIGHT);
        bg = buffer.getGraphics();
        paintComponent(bg);
        g.drawImage(buffer, 0, 0, null);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        if(loaded){
            render(g2);
        }
    }

    public abstract void render(Graphics2D g);
    }
}
```

Inside of the `Gamepanel.class` looks like this:

```
package com.platformer.subpanels;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import com.platformer.input.GameKeys;
import com.platformer.main.Start;
import com.platformer.main.Subpanel;
import com.platformer.objects.ObjectController;

public class Gamepanel extends Subpanel{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    ObjectController objectController;

    GameKeys key;

    public void load(){
        objectController = new ObjectController();
        this.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
                objectController.character.setVelX(1);
            }
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                objectController.character.setVelX(0);
            }
        });
    }

    public void tick(){
        objectController.tick();
    }

    public void render(Graphics2D g){
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, Start.WIDTH, Start.HEIGHT);

        objectController.render(g);
    }
}
```

The `GameKeys` is the KeyListener that I was previously using. Now in the code as you see, I am using a custom KeyAdapter to test it out. It still doesn't work.

The `GameKeys.class` looks like this:

```
package com.platformer.input;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import com.platformer.objects.ObjectController;
import com.platformer.subpanels.Gamepanel;

public class GameKeys extends KeyInput{

    private ObjectController objectController;
    private com.platformer.objects.Character character;

    public GameKeys(Gamepanel panel, ObjectController objectController){
        super(panel);
        this.objectController = objectController;
        this.character = this.objectController.character;
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        switch(e.getKeyCode()){
        case KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE:
            System.exit(0);
        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
            character.setVelX(1);
        }
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
        switch(e.getKeyCode()){
        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
            character.setVelX(0);
        }
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }
}
```

and it's based on `KeyInput.class`:

```
package com.platformer.input;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public abstract class KeyInput implements KeyListener{
    public KeyInput(JPanel panel){
        panel.addKeyListener(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Uhhh you  named a class "Object"? Don't  do that.

Comment: Yeah I know lol I figured but I was too late. I should probably change it to like "gameObject" or something. Too much trouble with java.lang.Object.

Comment: just to clarify: the problem is that adding in `c.setVelX(0);` breaks your collision detection?

Comment: Please post a small runnable example as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @RussellUhl Yes whenever I add `c.setVelX(0);` the collision detection stops working. However if I just animate `c.setVelX(1);` and scrap the whole keyboard it still works.

Comment: @dbank Ok if you want me to I'll post a bit more background code. It'll take some time however.

Comment: what is `tick()`?  How does that get called?  from a different thread?  is `x` an `int` or a `double`?

Comment: @programmersdude I think don't think the code snippets provide enough context for us to help you debug, which is why I suggest an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I will edit my example. Here is the src.zip download while I do that: http://goo.gl/0uf6vT

Comment: @RussellUhl The `tick()` gets called from a `JPanel`-based class called `GamePanel`. It is run by an implementable `JPanel` and `Thread`. Other things in the `tick()` class (e.g. `System.out.println("loop");`) work fine.

Comment: ok, now define "doesn't work".  Does your detection just stop altogether and your character runs through the object and off the screen (or whatever), or does the character stop somewhere in the middle of the object?

Comment: @RussellUhl I'm sorry about the lack of information in my question. By "doesn't work" I mean that the animation slows down whenever the character touches the object.

Comment: Slows down...but does not stop?

Comment: Yes, like the KeyListener is causing it to keep moving, but the collision wants it to stop and while they are battling, the KeyListener is winning a little more so the animation is going slower.

Comment: @RusselUhl If you wish you could check it out here: https://goo.gl/0uf6vT

Comment: @RussellUhl `x` is a double.

Comment: random question: are you on linux, per chance?  Specifically, is your app running on linux?  (allowing for it to be running over X11)

Comment: No, it's on non-virtual Windows 7.

Comment: Consider seriously reducing the amount of code in your post by providing an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). KeyListener are not your friend, look at Swing KeyBindings instead, they are much more consistent and reliable.

Comment: Thank you all for all your help. For now, I have added a `if(!objectController.character.isCollision())`, then only animate, inside of my GameKeys class and added a `isCollision()` in Character which returns if it is colliding with anything. If anyone would like to share again why this isn't working, it would be greatly appreciated! But for now, I have a workaround and as long as it's working somehow I'll still be fine! Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a sort-of workaround. I added a simple boolean,

```
public void isCollision(){
    return collision;
}
```

and a `collision` object that fits into:

```
for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
    if(this.bounds.getRCol().intersects(objects.get(i).bounds.getLCol())){
       collision = true;
       setVelX(0);
    }else{collision = false;}
}
```

Then this was modified from the GameKeys.class:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    if(!objectController.character.isCollision()){
        objectController.character.setVelX(1);
    }
}
```